# Access Crosstab Report

Tags: excel, report, crosstab

I am fairly new to access and have a database report issue I can't seem to figure out (even with several posts on the topic :/ )

The database houses audit information from 200+ stores. The audit answers are text, not numeric, and the audit date can be any day.  I want to create a report that lists the audit question as row headers, the most recent three audit dates as column headers, and the audit answers as the data.

I have a form that allows the user to select the store, and that feeds the crosstab query.  It works, except it does not limit to most recent three dates.  The table that feeds the query also lists visit number, so I thought I could do something with the max of visit number but to no avail.

The main issue though is now I cannot get a crosstab report to generate any data.  I have found several example pieces of code from back in the day that I have tried, but each tries to generate a row and grand total.  Since these are text data fields, the totals will not work and while I have tried removing the pieces of code I think are appropriate, it still does not generate the correct report.

A second option I thought of trying was to export the crosstab query to excel but I am also stuck there.

Any help would be VERY appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your skill level, this may be difficult.  My approach would be a bunch of subqueries, but it won't be pretty.  Let's say your stores are uniquely identified by StoreID, your audit dates are Audit Date, and your audit results are in a single text field AuditResults. It'll be up to you to figure out the details, but here's a rough outline:

Get all your data into a single table with 1-3 rows per StoreID (1 per audit date):

1. Make a simple query that groups by StoreID and returns max (AuditDate).  Call it `Qry1a`.
2. Join Qry1a back to the audit table to return the results from the most recent audit.  Include a `daterank` column that is hardcoded to 1.  Call it `Qry1b`.
3. Repeat a and b two more times to get the results from the 2nd and 3rd most recent audits (You can left join onto Qry1 and Qry2 to remove those results).  Call those `Qry2b` and `Qry3b`.
4. Using inner joins with your source table and `Qry1b`,`Qry2b`, and `Qry3b`, make a query that return a max of 3 rows per StoreID.

With this new table, make a new query and group by StoreID:

1. For the first columns, you'll use something like `LastAudit: max(iif(DateRank=1,AuditResults,""))`
2. Repeat the previous step to get the next 2 audits changing daterank to 2 and 3 respectively.

The advantage of this approach is that it can handle stores with less than 3 audits or if you have a constantly changing list of stores (because storeIDs aren't hardcoded anywhere).